# Bash input for multiple file

Tags: bash, unix

I have thousands of two set of files one with name.ext and another files name ending with name.ext.in, so for every name.ext there is a name.ext.in and now i have to pass this as argument to a script such as customise.pl name.ext name.ext.in. I am doing like

```
#!/bin/bash 

FILE1=$.ext
FILE2=$.ext.in

customise.pl $FILE1 $FILE2
```

but no success. Any idea?

Comment: You surely have to loop through the list of files, in order to run your `customise.pl` for each pair.

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in *.ext; do 
    customise.pl "$i" "$i.in"
done
```

Comment: Just in case there is whitespace in any of the filenames, it is probably a better idea to do `customise.pl "$i" "$i.in"`.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the comments to the other answers, you probably want something like this:

```
for file in *.ext; do
    customise.pl "$file" "${file%.*}.new.psl"
done
```

The `${file%.*}` syntax substitutes only the part of `$file` up until its last dot. You can check the manpages for Bash or Dash for more information on it if you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run customise.pl for each pair of files, you can do it like this in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `ls *.ext`
do
  customise.pl $i $i.in
done
```

Comment: `for i in $(ls *.ext)` has the problem that it doesn't deal with whitespace and quoting properly. `for i in *.ext` works better.

Comment: if it is like name.ext and the second file is like name.XYZ.in where XYZ is a common in the header of the second file.

Comment: Hi thanks, but the problem is that only name is similar 
I have thousands of two set of files one with name.ext and another files for the same name ending with name.new.psl, so for every name.ext there is a name.new.psl and now i have to pass this as argument to a script such as customise.pl name.ext name.new.psl. Any idea for loop in bash. The first name is common for the each name.ext and name.new.psl like

perl customise.pl name.ext name.new.psl

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest form is

```
    for f in "*.ext"
    do                 
         customise.pl  $f.ext $f.ext.in      
    done
```

OUTPUT:

Comment: Hi thanks. 
I have thousands of two set of files one with name.ext and another files for the same name ending with name.new.psl, so for every name.ext there is a name.new.psl and now i have to pass this as argument to a script such as customise.pl name.ext name.new.psl. Any idea for loop in bash. The first name is common for the each name.ext and name.new.psl like

perl customise.pl name.ext name.new.psl

Answer (score 0):

another way.

```
ls *.ext |xargs -i customise.pl {} {}.in
```