# Bash loop for multiple files

Tags: bash, unix

I have thousands of two set of files, one with `name.ext` and another set for the same name ending with `name.new.psl`. So for every `name.ext` there is a `name.new.psl`.  Now I have to pass this as arguments to a script such as `customise.pl name.ext name.new.psl`

Any ideas for a loop in bash? The first name is common for each `name.ext` and `name.new.psl` like:

```
perl customise.pl name.ext name.new.psl
```

Comment: Don't re-post questions http://stackoverflow.com/q/21515411/3076724

Answer (score 4):

```
for f in *.ext ; do
    perl customise.pl "${f}" "${f/%.txt/.new.psl}"
done
```

Will do it for you in the current working directory.

Comment: Is the `%` in `${f/%.txt/.new.psl}` conflating the `${f%.txt}` notation with `${f/.txt/.new}`?

Comment: No. The `%` is used to anchor the pattern to the end of the string, similar to the regular expression `\.txt$`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffle chepner is right. IMO it's more reliable to match extensions this way.

Answer (score 2):

```
for fname in *.ext
do
    perl customise.pl "$fname" "${fname%.ext}.new.psl"
done
```

The above does not require any special bash features.  So, it is compatible with, for example, `dash` which is the default shell (`/bin/sh`) on debian-derived distributions.

The trick above is that `${fname%.ext}` tells the shell to remove the text `.ext` from the end of `$fname`, leaving just the "name" part.  Thus, `"${fname%.ext}.new.psl"` removes `.ext` adds the `.new.psl` extension.

The file names in the code above are in double-quotes.  This is so that this script will work even if the file names have spaces in them.

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in `ls *.ext`; do NAME=`echo $i | awk -F '.' '{print $1}'`; perl customise.pl $NAME.ext $NAME.new.psl; done
```

Comment: Hi  the file names are like this and i got error busing suggested bashgi_322422812_ref_NC_015111.1_.fsa.shIDs.ext gi_322422812_ref_NC_015111.1_.fsa.shIDs.new.psl

Comment: Using `$(ls *.ext)` in place of `*.ext` is definitely seriously inferior.  The globbing notation `*.ext` manages with spaces and other special characters in the file names; the `$(ls *.ext)` notation breaks on file names containing spaces etc.

Comment: Never use `for i on $(cmd)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606864/ffmpeg-in-a-bash-pipe/19607361?stw=2#19607361

Comment: I agree with you. Zsolt Botykai answer is more appropriate

Comment: Thanks  Idriss Neumann

Comment: Hi these are the file names gi_322422812_ref_NC_015111.1_.fsa.shIDs.ext gi_322422812_ref_NC_015111.1_.fsa.shIDs.new.psl  and i have to run for every set like customise.pl gi_322422812_ref_NC_015111.1_.fsa.shIDs.new.psl gi_322422812_ref_NC_015111.1_.fsa.shIDs.ext . I tried the above ones but it is not working. Any idea?

Comment: Use Zsolt Botykai code 

    for f in *.ext ; do perl customise.pl "${f}" "${f/%.ext/.new.psl}";done

as my approach has several drawbacks, e.g. if filename contains several dots it doesn't work properly